# Android: how to supply thousands of pre saved images with a new app?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview, resources

I am new to Android development and trying to develop an app with information on collectibles.

In short: the app contains information on thousands of collectible items, each with its own information and properties. 
For this I want to set up a pre filled SQLITE database containing all the information. However each item also has an image connected to it.

The app will contain a listview showing all the items of a certain category (max 2k items per category). 
Each listview item will have some basic information like Title, Short description and a thumbnail.

The problem is now, that I don't know which is the correct way to handle the images. Searching the internet I already concluded that I should not
add the images themselves to the database, which makes sense.
I do know I can add images to the resources/drawable folders, but having thousands and thousands of images added here, does not feel as the correct way.

If I want to save paths of the images into the database (which is pre filled), where should I save all the images, so they are accessible with the newly shipped app?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: from where you get these images ?

Comment: I already have them available as png images on my computer. I got them supplied by my employer.

Comment: Are you able to involve a server that provides these images through api for this ?

Comment: Well in theory I could, but that would not be the preferred solution, as the app will require an internet connection that way. Because of the amount of pictures I'm afraid it will take up quite the bandwith cap.

Comment: so how can you feed your app, Do you  expect put all these images under app drawable folder ??

Comment: That's actually the issue, putting them all under the drawable does not seem like a valid solution. Because I don't have a lot of android experience, I was hoping someone could tell me another good solution to this. Are the only two options to feed: supplying them in drawable or downloading them by online api?

Comment: Do you expect to publish this app in Google play ?  how many clients will there be for your app ?

Comment: It will get published on Google Play yes, how many clients is hard to say, hoping to reach as much as possible, but it probably wont reach more then a couple of hundreds. I'm not afraid for the bandwith cap of the servers btw, more the users phone bandwith.

Comment: in such case, you need to an API with a  DB. You can get the image name from API and then download the respective image.

Comment: I will go and try that, downloading the image, and then saving them for reloading them a second time. Thank you for for your help.